# How to show something is not satisfiable using tree procedure?

Tags: logic

I want to prove that the following set is not satisfiable in logic:

$\neg\forall x(F(x)\rightarrow G(x),\neg\exists x F(x),\neg G(x))$

1.$\neg\forall x(F(x)\rightarrow G(x))$, hyp

2.$\neg\exists F(x)$, hyp

3.$\neg\exists G(x)$, hyp

4.$\exists x\neg (F(x)\rightarrow G(x))$, $R_{\neg\forall(1)}$

5.$\forall x\neg F(x)$, $R_{\neg\exists(2)}$

6.$\forall x\neg G(x)$, $R_{\neg\exists(3)}$

7.$\neg (F(a)\rightarrow G(a))$, $R_{\exists(4)}$

8.$F(a)$ X (inconsistent)

9.$\neg G(a)$

**I closed only one formula of the tree procedure, my teacher told me that it was enough not to satisfy the set, I don't understand why, shouldn't we try to show that $9$ is inconsistent too?**

Answer (score 1):

You have written the tree in the wrong way.

From step 7 you have derived :

> 8. $F(a)$ and 9. $\lnot G(a)$.

Now you have to apply The $\forall$-rule to 5. $∀x ¬F(x)$, deriving :

> 10. $\lnot F(a)$.

Now, based on 8. and 10., you can "cross" the path, because it contains $F(a), \lnot F(a)$, i.e. it is *inconsistent*, and thus *unsatisfiable*.